# Meaning of "...improve the age structure of farmers"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

I am reading a sheet about rural development program issued by Finnish government.

> Measures are foreseen to develop and raise agricultural productivity and competitiveness by improving the structure of agricultural production and seeking **to improve the age structure of farmers**.

There is a sentence in another related document from Czech government saying:

> In the recent past, the number of farm workers has continuously fallen and this has brought about an unfavourable age structure in both agriculture and forestry.

I suspect it means making farmers to be presented by younger citizen? I wouldn't care if it was from a non-official source, but as it's the government sheet, I am a bit surprised.

Or am I getting these sentences wrongly?

Comment: I believe it means there are not enough young farmers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_pyramid

Comment: Why are you surprised?

Comment: Well, having an image of usually politically correct and tolerant, it's strange to hear from government ageist statements hidden by using euphemisms.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov Ageism is when you discriminate against a specific person or a group because of their age. Analyzing the age distribution of a population and recognizing the danger of losing your country's agriculture is a legitimate function of the government.

Comment: I mean, by improving they mean adding more young citizen and by decreasing adding more old citizen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we should be using *profile* rather than *structure* in this context.

See:
Agriculture & Food, Ireland: [Age Profile of Farmers](https://www.agriculture.gov.ie/publications/2011/annualreviewandoutlookforagriculturefisheriesandfood20102011/farmstructures/ageprofileoffarmers/)

> There has been a decline in the number of farmers in the younger age categories over the period, with the proportion of farmers aged 44 or younger decreasing from 35% to 25%. However, Ireland has a higher percentage (7%) of farmers aged under 35 than the EU-27 average of 6%.

US Census Bureau:  [America’s Age Profile Told through Population Pyramids](http://blogs.census.gov/2016/06/23/americas-age-profile-told-through-population-pyramids/)

Future HR Trends:  [Profile of the global workforce: present and future](http://futurehrtrends.eiu.com/report-2015/profile-of-the-global-workforce-present-and-future/)